# How to press (windows+R) keys simultaneously using actions class of selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

1. How to press (windows+R) keys simultaneously using actions class of
   selenium?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve.  You will not be able to interact with anything outside of the browser...

Comment: I'm just curious to know if there exist any Keys or methods in action class to perform all the keyboard events which also inclused the keyboard events outside the browser's scope. 
So as per you comment we cant automate the keyboard events outside browser scope. Is that correct?

Comment: Selenium is purely in the context of the browser by design.  If you want to use the WebDriver API to automate windows programs you could have a look at https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/1d4ac13c30576f3254ba30ce9eb8673a40e223bc/Tests/WebDriverAPI/SendKeys.cs I have no idea how good it is though